# Estimating Gamma PDF parameters from data with negative increments

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, nonparametric, particle-filter

Say we have collected data, and from a physical perspective we know that the collected data should increase positively with time. However the data looks more like this: [image: Collected Data]

This data shown in the figure is generated as follows:

We first generate 100 random values sampled from a Gamma PDF with **shape parameter = 0.78** and **scale parameter = 1.1**, lets call this vector of a 100 data points **Xgamma**

We then generated another 100 random values sampled from a Gaussian PDF with
**mean = 0** and **standard deviation = 10**, lets call this vector of a 100 data points **Xnoise**

Now let's call **Xgammapro** the cumulative sum of Xgamma, basically the gamma process created by the individual random values that were sampled from the gamma PDF

Data 1 =  cumulative sum (Xgamma + Xnoise)

Data 2 = Xgammapro + Xnoise

What should be the best approach if we wanted to estimate the parameters of a Gamma PDF from Data 1 and Data 2 ?

Is there a good way to separate the noise from the real data ? And what should be done in case the noise is not Gaussian ?